# Pictures icon is broken after hacking registry to change location

Tags: windows-registry, windows-11

[enter image description here][1]I recently installed Windows 11 and uninstalled Onedrive. I then changed the location of the Desktop, Documents and Pictures folders from Onedrive to their %USERPROFILE% locations. I changed the location for Desktop in the folder properties but had to change the registry entries in User Shell Folders to move Documents and Pictures. Now the Pictures folder icon is displaying what looks like the old registry entry, but only under Home. When I navigate to the username folder the Pictures icon is normal. Any idea how to fix it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pD10j.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5QoV.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1tTE.jpg

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window. Type the following command-line: `reg query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"`

Please post the output of the above command.

Comment: Didnt you ask this elsewhere?

Comment: @w32sh Added a pic of the output

Comment: @Rohit Gupta nope